# How to use snowflake CALL SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL with a template

Tags: email, templates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using CALL SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL in a stored procedure:

```
query_email := '' call system$send_email (''''''|| notif || '''''' ,'''''' || mlist || '''''' , ''''New ...'' ||'' are ready to upload...'''' , '''''' || content || '''''');'' ;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_email ;
```

and would like to know if there is a way to include images or even completely templating the sent email.
Any one has tried this already?

I searched in stackoverflow, read the documentation and found nothing.

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Send Email documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures/system_send_email#optional) states that mime-type may be either text/plain or text/html. HTML would allow for a lot of potential formatting options including possibly image attachment.

Templating is not part of the base functionality. You would need to wrap that up in a customer stored procedure. A Python stored procedure may be ideal for this. Note that you would not use Python to send the email, only for building and formatting.

UPDATE: Snowflake now makes it easy to attach an image to email. See [Hey Snowflake, Send Me a Fancy HTML Email](https://hoffa.medium.com/hey-snowflake-send-me-a-fancy-email-fe04ad2c9888)

Comment: Ok about the MIME type but how to declare an image storage? I mean, is there a way to declare an external folder or something else? Maybe the image must be in a TABLE too. Let me try this.

Comment: There is no way, that I'm aware of, to include anything in the email that isn't pure text/html. Obviously you can hard-code a link to an image in your html but that image would need to be accessible by the recipient